Looking for the title of a short story for my students to read about a woman searching for the last man alive
Read this short story as a sophomore in 1983-1984.  I am now a freshmen English teacher and want to include it into my class. The plot involves a woman searching for the last man alive. She thinks it might be a guy she once knew and that she told him that she would only date him if he was the last man alive.  When she finds him, he offers her the opportunity to be the last woman alive.

Anyone else reading the last sentence as "When she finds him, he makes a sinister threat."?

Checkmate by Edward Wellen from Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine, December 1980; it's on the Internet Archive here.
Searching for the last man on Earth:

She walked out onto the floor. The vast maze of the production line
was almost entirely automated. She spotted just three workers among
the rolling pills and marching bottles. Down among the capping and
sealing machines she braced the first.
The sister popped her gum thoughtfully. "Vernon Gardner? Ain’t that
the name of the guy that’s still alive? What would he be doing here?
Hell no, I ain’t seen him.”
"I heard he worked here once — Before.”
"Well, he don’t work here now. Believe you me, I would’ve noticed
him.”

She thinks it might be a guy she once knew and that she told him that she would only date him if he was the last man alive.

When Vernon ventured to inform her that he loved her, something she
took for granted, and when he compounded that by propositioning her,
she did not say, "Get lost, you creep.” But that was the burden of her
response. Because she did say, could not resist saying, "Maybe if you
were the last man on earth ...”

Disease:

The commemorators had hardly scattered to their homes when Checkmate
struck.
"Checkmate,” some headline-writer called the plague, and the name
stuck. The disease spread with Concorde speed. It was no localized
Egyptian plague. It left no spot on Earth untouched. Human males of
all ages, climes, and persuasions dropped like sprayed flies.

And turnabout:

He was mad, of course, but gloriously mad. No, it was not all madness.
Above all, it was love. If that was madness she was mad too.
"You did it all for me?” She wanted to hear him say it.
And he did. Readily. "Of course it’s all because of you, Bonnie.”
"Then take me.”
Almost at once emptiness filled her.
Vernon gazed through her as though seeing all the world’s lonely
lovely women.
"Things have changed, Bonnie.”
She stood stunned, her head in a roar.
Slowly he focused on her and gave her a half smile.
"Maybe if you were the last woman in the world. . . .”
After the shock of that passed, Bonnie looked thoughtful.


oof! what an ending. That was a punch to the gut. Nice find!

I remembered this one right off the top of my head - now that's memorable.

Thank you for the help.  As a new English teacher, but older in years, graduated high school in 1986, I have the freedom to pick short stories and add them to the reading list for my students.

Glad to help. Please give me a checkmark, so this answer is marked as Accepted, and come back with more questions

@Andrew "Please give me a checkmark" - Maybe if you are the last question answerer in the world...
